# ¿De qué manera puedo mover una columna de posición en una tabla en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla 'Orders' de northwind, está modificada con una columna extra llamada **sucID**, lo que no sé como hacer es el mover dicha columna hacia la izquierda como lo muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacerlo desde script, no puedo hacerlo con un **select**. ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar? :(

Comment: quieres moverlo solo en un resultado de select query o quieres cambiar la estructura de la tabla? Si quieres hacer el segundo, no es posible hacerlo con un sql script. Informacion [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15). Tiene que drop table y recrearlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta corta es: SQL Server no soporta cambiar el orden de las columnas de una tabla, esto está [claramente documentado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table).

Una manera de hacerlo es crear una nueva tabla con las mismas columnas y tipos de datos, en el orden que te interesa. Esto requerirá tomar las precauciones, por ejemplo, restringir por un tiempo el acceso a la base de datos mientras se realiza el proceso.

Dicho esto en el SQL Server Management Studio soporta realizar la operación, realizando tras bambalinas el proceso descrito anteriormente. Para hacerlo en el SSMS, debes primero habilitar la opción de configuración que impide guardar cambios que re-crean tablas, entra en *Tools*/*Options*/*Designers*/*Table and database designers* y desmarca la casilla *Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation*.

[image: Opción para permitir re-crear tablas]

Luego, con botón derecho, entra al *modo de diseño* de la tabla de tu interés, y con el ratón puedes seleccionar y arrastrar las columnas hasta que queden en el orden deseado, tomándolas desde la primera casilla (dónde se muestra la flecha > al estar seleccionada la columna).

Finalmente, presionas el botón de guardar.

Ensaya esta operación en un entorno que no sea productivo, de preferencia con el mismo volumen de datos, para evaluar que termine con éxito y cuanto tiempo toma realizarse.

Una observación muy importante de la documentación es esta (el resaltado es mío):

> Precaución
>
> Si cambia el orden de las columnas de una tabla, **el código y las aplicaciones que dependen de un orden de columnas determinado pueden verse afectados**. Los elementos afectados pueden ser consultas, vistas, procedimientos almacenados, funciones definidas por el usuario y aplicaciones cliente. **Tenga en cuenta las consecuencias antes de realizar cualquier cambio en el orden de las columnas**. El procedimiento recomendado es especificar el orden en que las columnas se devuelven en el nivel de aplicación y de consulta. **No debe confiar en el uso de `SELECT *` para devolver todas las columnas en un orden esperado** según el orden en que están definidos en la tabla. **Especifique siempre las columnas por nombre en las consultas** y aplicaciones en el orden en que desea que aparezcan.

A pesar de las recomendaciones, hay personas que escriben código, tanto `select`'s como `insert`'s y su código circundante, que hacen que sus aplicaciones puedan romperse de haber un cambio como el que pretendes hacer. De hecho, el querer hacer ese cambio da referencia que estás en un sistema o entorno que depende de dicho orden, en otro caso, simplemente cambias el orden en que se escriben las columnas en el `select` y no necesitarías hacderlo.

Al hacerlo vas por tu cuenta y riesgo.

Comment: Pana, muchas gracias, me sirvió demasiado! De verdad gracias por la explicación **tan detallada** que me diste, te lo agradezco. Un abrazo!!

Answer (score 0):

**ALTER TABLE** Orders **MODIFY COLUMN** sucID (datatype) **AFTER** costumerID;

si no te permitió con eso, intentá con

**ALTER TABLE** Orders **CHANGE COLUMN** sucID (datatype) **AFTER** costumerID;

La sintaxis que te doy como ejemplo es especifica para mySQL. Si estas usando PostgreSQL u otra base de datos no va a funcionar.

Otra cosa a aclarar, donde te pongo entre paréntesis (datatype) tenés que aclarar por ejemplo si tiene default value o NOT NULL, es decir, las características de dicha columna.

Comment: La pregunta indica, en sus etiquetas, que es para sql-server y la respuesta que das claramente no aplica para este motor de base de datos, te invito a leer [answer]. Un saludo.